# Chamar Parametros de Sistema usando Js para o FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Há alguma maneira de definir minTime/maxTime/slotDuration do FullCalendar nos parametros de Sistema do odoo e depois com java chamar esses valores e implementar no calendário? i.e. Definir 3 Parametros de Sistema (StartTime, StopTime and SlotDuration) e chamar esses valores.

Tenho isto: (Graças a @Jigar Patel)

```
odoo.define('anser_ricardo', function(require) {
  "use strict";
  var CalendarModel = require('web.CalendarModel');
  CalendarModel.include({
    _getFullCalendarOptions: function() {
      var res = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
      return _.extend(res, {
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '22:00:00',
        slotDuration: '00:10:00',
      });
    },
  });
});
```

E criei 3 parametros:

```
<record id='start_time_key' model='ir.config_parameter'>
            <field name='key'>start_time_key</field>
            <field name='value'>08:00:00</field>
        </record>
        <record id='stop_time_key' model='ir.config_parameter'>
            <field name='key'>stop_time_key</field>
            <field name='value'>22:00:00</field>
        </record>
        <record id='slotDuration_time_key' model='ir.config_parameter'>
            <field name='key'>slotDuration_time_key</field>
            <field name='value'>00:10:00</field>
        </record>
```

Preciso de receber esses valores para minTime/maxTime/slotDuration, e não os definir diretamente no código.
Algo como isto:

```
 return _.extend(res, {

       minTime:  get.start_time_key,

       maxTime: get.stop_time_key,

       slotDuration: get.slotDuration_time_key,
```

Alguem me consegue ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: Eu uso via ajax e retorno pro fullcalendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está a resposta:

```
odoo.define('anser_ricardo', function (require) {

"use strict";

var CalendarModel = require('web.CalendarModel');

CalendarModel.include({

    _getFullCalendarOptions: function () {
        var res = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            return _.extend(res, {
            minTime: this.custom_fc_options.start_time_key,
            maxTime: this.custom_fc_options.stop_time_key,
            slotDuration: this.custom_fc_options.slotDuration_time_key,
        });
    },
    _loadCalendar: function () {
        var self = this;
        var args = arguments;
        var sup = this._super;
        var defs = [];
        this.custom_fc_options = {};

        _.each(['start_time_key', 'stop_time_key', 'slotDuration_time_key], function (param) {
            var def = self._rpc({
                model: 'ir.config_parameter',
                method: 'get_param',
                args: [param]
            }).then(function (res) {
                self.custom_fc_options[param] = res;
            });
            defs.push(def);
        });

        return $.when.apply($, defs).then(function () {
            return sup.apply(self, args);
        });
    },

});

});
```